# RGBA png alpha processing

Tags: c, png, alpha

I have an RGBA PNG file that is(I think) the capture of a signature from a digitizing tablet. Extracting out the image, ALL RGB triplets are 0,0,0 and the alpha channel values are non zero if the pixel is to carry a tone in the final image. I get all of that.

This PNG only has a IHDR, IDAT, and IEND chunks.

> My first question is, are my RGB pixels considered the foreground or
> the background? What might be the proper terminology to describe this
> file/image?
>
> What equation do I use to apply the alpha to the RGB.

Looking at the alpha values, I can see how to come up with a number, but what general equation would be used generate the appropriate RGB value, avoiding divide by 0 or overflow value errors if my RGBs had started out with non zero values.

I have been through the PNG spec and there's something I just don't get.

BTW, I am ultimately producing, in C, a PCL file intended for printing directly to a PCL LaserJet.

Comment: Sounds like a grayscale image, using alpha as gray (inappropriately so, I might add).

Comment: Your analysis is sound. As I don't create the image myself, I guess I am committed to read the entire image to verify that the only data is in the alpha channel. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The image you display last is the foreground image. There is no foreground and background in a single image.

This link shows how to blend an image with alpha to another image.:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing#Alpha_blending